# How to load a matlab file (.mat) in windows if it was originally saved in UNIX

Tags: matlab, unix

I'm trying to open a .mat file in the windows environment but it is failing. It was created in a Unix environment. Also note that this file was first put in a .tar file first, ftp via binary method. The file opens in Unix and I don't think it was corrupted in any way.

Comment: Did you compare the md5hashes? Matlab files are platform-agnostic.

Comment: error: Number of columns on line 1 of ASCII file ~/myfile.mat
must be the same as previous lines.

Comment: is this a very large .mat file? it may be helpful to make a smaller example (if you are able), something you could potentially post, and see if you get the same error.

Comment: UPDATE:
i did an experiment. i created a .mat file in unix and transfered over to windows and it opened without a problem. then i made made a .tar archive of that file and transfered it over to windows, and it failed. i think the way winzip is unarchiving the .tar file is the problem. anyone know how to fix this?


SOLVED: in winzip options>configuration>miscellaneous, uncheck 'TAR file smart CR/LF conversion'

thanks all for the help

Comment: please post your last comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The *.mat file format is platform agnostic.  The OS does not matter.

There are a number of variants of the *.mat file which have been used, and older versions cannot always read formats saved with newer versions.  You can save to an older version using flags available in the  `save` command.  These formats have been updated as the Matlab feature set has demanded a more flexible file format, and as other technologies have advanced, most notably HDF5 in the recent version.

Finally, the `save` command supports an ASCII formatted option.  I suspect this is your current problem, based on your comment regarding the error message received.

---

To address your current problem:

First, check to see if the file is an ASCII file.  The easiest way is to simply open it in notepat, wordpad, or even the matlab editor.  If the file is text, then this becomes a file parsing problem, and the appropriate use of `fscanf` shoudl fix the problem.

If the file is actually a binary *.mat file then you probably have a Matlab version incompatability.  Yuo can either go back to the source unix environment and save to an older version (eg `save ....  -v7`) or update the Matlab version of the reading computer.

Comment: great answer. However, the UNIX matlab is an older version than the one on windows

Comment: UPDATE:
i did an experiment. i created a .mat file in unix and transfered over to windows and it opened without a problem. then i made made a .tar archive of that file and transfered it over to windows, and it failed. i think the way winzip is unarchiving the .tar file is the problem. anyone know how to fix this?


SOLVED: in winzip options>configuration>miscellaneous, uncheck 'TAR file smart CR/LF conversion'

thanks all for the help